# SQLite model adapter for Geddy or Express

Tags: node.js, express, geddy

Can someone help me out figuring how to write a model adapter for geddyjs or expressjs web frameworks for NodeJS?

I'm following this tutorial but they persist data in memory, I want to know how to do it with sqlite since I'm starting to get to know it.

Thanks

http://geddyjs.org/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

There's a new Tutorial up on nettuts that will show you how to do a mongo adapter. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/persisting-your-todo-list-with-mongodb-and-geddy/

You could do the same thing for SQLite.

We're working on adding this stuff into Geddy core. Check out the progress here: 
https://github.com/mde/geddy/pull/78

Answer (score 0):

Just an update, SQLite is now one of the supported adapters in model.